# Facebook API: How to acquire access_token server-side and use it client-side?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, koala

I am building a rails app that scrapes user's graph API content regularly. My first approach was to do this completely serverside, using Omniauth for authenticating and Koala for interacting with Facebook on the server. I had to run a background process to do this.

However I realized it can become very expensive and am thinking about the option of doing it both server-side and client-side. I still need to do server-side because I need to populate content even when the user is not on the site, but at least when the user is on the site it makes more sense to do all the polling client side. This way, my server wouldn't need to scrape FB server as often, so the cost stays low, and the users are happier because when they can receive updates as often as they want, using FB javascript SDK

I'm not sure if this is possible. Currently I know how to do this completely server side, or completely client-side. But I don't know how to acquire access_token from server-side and use that information on the client-side as well to let the client do most of the polling. I would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

"I am building a rails app that scrapes user's graph API content regularly."  Don't just this, it will be too costly.  Implement the Graph API's Real-Time updates for the user and store the information.  This way you're notified immediately when something changes and also you don't have to "waste" polling calls to the API that return nothing new than the last call did.  Then if you want to you write a poller in your clientside that polls your server side data store of user information.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually spent several hours reading through documents and this was one of the new things I learned. But it's still tricky. Since asking this question last night I've managed to implement the client side polling module, and it seems to be working fine but I have no idea how this is working :( I guess maybe once the user authenticates once with the serverside using Omniauth, it gets stored in the cookie and I don't have to worry about the client side authentication.

Comment: Actually I do thank you for your comment, but I still haven't got my answer. I don't know why this question was downvoted (maybe it's a newbie question?), but I still have this problem. How I'm tackling this issue right now is, first I use Koala gem to handle server side scraping. But for client side, I just use Facebook's js api, which uses the Facebook session of the user who's currently signed into Facebook, which means the server side might be crawling user A's content, while client side might be crawling whoever is using the computer right now. Do you know if there's a solution to this?

Comment: As I pointed out in my original answer, scraping is not the way to do this.  Use the Graph API's Real-Time Updates mechanism to get instant updates.